# How can I get a directory name by a window dialog called in shell script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, nautilus

I have a shell script and want to get a directory name chosen by a nautilus dialog (or other tool). Ex:

```
#/usr/bin/bash
# choosing a path name
export my_directory=`pwd`

# open a nautilus dialog (1)
# which command may I do here to get the dirercory?
my_directory=`nautilus ${my_directory}`

# my directory now has the directory chosen by nautilus dialog
echo "my directory is ${my_directory}"
```

Is it possible with ubuntu native components?

Comment: Have you considered using `zenity --file-selection` instead?

Comment: preferably using native components, but if is not possible, could be of a  canonical partner (preferably opensource/free). I'm just taking a look on zenith.

Comment: Zenity is native.

Comment: Thanks a lot steldriver and Jacob. It's [so easy!](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/file-selection.html.en).

Comment: @steeldriver want to convert it into an answer?

Comment: It's really an important tool. Waiting for the 'difficult solution' :).

Comment: @gwarah What do you mean, zenity is not sufficient for you?

Comment: I don't mean it @JacobVlijm. Just the opposite, zennity is just the solution I was looking for.  I know something of scripting command line, now I'm learning a little bit more about better components like this one. Said **difficult solution**, because it is in the link **so easy**.

Comment: @gwarah Great, isn't it. If you use Gtk, you can also use `GtkFileChooserDialog`: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html, but for a simple script, Zenity is great. Would you mind if I converted it into an answer? The question should have an answer.

Comment: Yes, I think it's more didactic, steeldriver could answer using zenity and you using this tool you suggest. The better code (IMHO) wins this 'challenge'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42329/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-gwarah).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One fairly straightforward way would be to use `zenity` e.g.

```
# basic syntax
zenity --file-selection --directory --filename="$PWD/"
```

A simple code (source: [gnome zenity help](http://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/file-selection.html.en))

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=`zenity --file-selection --directory --title="Select a File"`
case $? in
         0)
                echo "\"$DIR\" selected.";;
         1)
                echo "No file selected.";;
        -1)
                echo "An unexpected error has occurred.";;
esac
```

See `zenity --help-file-selection` for additional options.